# PyAudio is not picking up audio

Tags: python, pyaudio

I'm running a python program and i'm using PyAudio to pick up my voice. My volume is on and I even tried it with airpods but it's not picking up anything. This is the code that i am running.

```
r=sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:

print("Listening...")
        
r.pause_threshold = 1 #use for recognizer hold
       
 
r.energy_threshold = 1000
        
audio = r.listen(source)

try :

print("Recognizing...")

query = r.recognize_google(audio, Language = 'en-us')

print(f"user said: {query}\n")

speak("okay")

except Exception as e:
        
print("Say that again please")
        
return "None"
    
return query
```

The output i get is

```
Listening...
Recognizing...
Say that again please
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction as to how to fix this I would appreciate it!

Comment: Have you tried `r.speak("okay")` instead of `speak("okay")`?

Comment: yeah, still got the same error.

Comment: I suggest changing `print("Say that again please")` to `print(e)` then add the output to the question so we can help you better..